# getting parent index with jquery

Tags: jquery

I know there is another question with an answer to my question, however one solution that was said to be newer does not work for me.

so I have something like:

```
<ul>
 <li><div class="thumb"></div></li>
 <li><div class="thumb"></div></li>
 <li><div class="thumb"></div></li>
</ul>


$("ul li div.thumb").live("click",function(){

alert($(this).parent().index());

});
```

I want to retrieve the index of the li, however the solution is not working for me.

EDIT:

Ok my actual code has children within div.thumb:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="thumb"><div class="inner">3</div></div></li>
 <li><div class="thumb"><div class="inner">3</div></div></li>
 <li><div class="thumb"><div class="inner">3</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

I didn't think it would matter since div thumb is being clicked. I'm getting -1  for any .thumb clicked
    ​

Comment: It should be working. Post the rest of your code and your HTML.

Comment: it should work as works here http://jsfiddle.net/7YCpY/

Comment: ah I'm still using jquery 1.3 because the drupal installation has it. Upgrading might break existing modules.

Comment: updated code with a potential problem

Comment: Ok so the problem is my old jquery version that I must use so that everything in drupal doesnt break.

Answer (score 0):

Yep it does work. Please show some code.

Did you put the jQuery within the ready() function?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("ul li div.thumb").live("click",function(){
        alert($(this).parent().index());
    });
});
```